# Call a javascript function on a crossorigin server

Tags: javascript, php

Hello i am trying to run the following script on a different server:

```
$$.find('button#reboot').on('click', function() {
        var popup = new mimosa.popup();
        popup.title('Confirmation');
        popup.content('<p>Rebooting will cause service interruption.</p><p>Do you wish to continue?</p>');
        popup.ok(function() {
            mimosa.system.reboot("Reboot Button");
        });
        popup.cancel();
        popup.show();
    });
```

can anybody tell me or give me an example on how that's done?

Comment: Unclear how you want to run it..... We need more details.

Comment: So what's your problem, the script is being blocked?

Comment: I don't understand what's your problem here...

Comment: my script is not being block but I'm not able to find a way to make that script run from my server i was thinking maybe you could give an idea of how it works, or if i should use curl

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking to do is communicate between window objects cross-origin.  This can be accomplished using the `postMessage` api.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

You'd have to set up a post-message listener on your server. When that listener receives the postMessage, have it run the script.

Receiving window:

```
window.addEventListener("runScript", receiveMessage, false);

function receiveMessage(event)
{
  if (event.origin !== "http://example.org:8080") {
    return;
  }
  ...
}
```